# How to change color of a rectangle with a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a ListView in WPF with text and colored rectangles. Additionaly there is a textbox and a rectangle with binding to the ListView. The selected Item of the Listbox is displayed in the textbox and the rectangle:

```
<ListView x:Name="StatusOEMList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="50,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" ItemsSource="{Binding OEM}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding value}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Farbe">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="50,272,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=StatusOEMList, Path=SelectedItem.value}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding ElementName=StatusOEMList, Path=SelectedItem.color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="192,272,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" MouseLeftButtonDown="rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown" Cursor="Pen"/>
```

When I change the text, the change is transfered back to the ListView. Nice.
But how can I change the color of the rectangle and transfer the change back to the ListView?
I implemented a ColorPicker to change the color fo the rectangle:

```
void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    colorDialog.SelectedColor = ((SolidColorBrush)((Rectangle)sender).Fill).Color;
    colorDialog.Owner = this;
    if ((bool)colorDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        ((Rectangle)sender).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(colorDialog.SelectedColor);
    }
}
```

I think I am overwriting the Binding in the Rectangle.Fill there. How can I just change the color and keep the Binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed overwriting Rectangle.Fill binding with local value. Try changing the bound property instead:

```
void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    colorDialog.SelectedColor = ((SolidColorBrush)((Rectangle)sender).Fill).Color;
    colorDialog.Owner = this;
    if ((bool)colorDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        var vm = StatusOEMList.SelectedItem as MyViewModel;
        vm.color = colorDialog.SelectedColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are ignoring mvvm design principle and manipulating viewmodel from the view, should consider making the buttondown action to launch from the viewmodel instead code behind, thus only updating the binding source.